# Embed php file into react app using npm php-express not working

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to embed a php file into my react application using `npm php-express`. I have php installed on my machine and the environment variable set. My file structure is as follows:

```
../server/views/php/file.php
../app
../build
```

However, when I run the react app using `npm start` and click on the php file, I get the error: `Could not open input file:` If the file is not in the `server/views/php/` directory and I click I get the error: `Failed to lookup view "file" in views directory "..\views\php" at Function.render`

Wondering if anyone could help me figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

My php middleware code in the react app looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const phpExpress = require('php-express')({
  binPath: 'php',
});

const setup = app => {
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views/php'));
  app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
  app.set('view engine', 'php');

  app.all(/\/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);
  app.all(/\/(file).*/i, phpExpress.router);
};

module.exports = { setup };
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is a Node.js framework for building an HTTP server with.

`php-express` is Express middleware and is designed to work with Express.

React is a JavaScript framework for building client applications with.

You can't use `php-express` inside a React app because:

- React isn't Express.
- You can't make HTTP requests **to** a client.

---

You could use Express to write an HTTP server and use `php-express` to run PHP through it.

You could then make requests to that server from the React application. This could be cross-origin (if you set up the server to grant permission with CORS) or you could build the React application and deploy the production rules so they are hosted by the same server.

However, unless you have a strong need to mix PHP and server-side JavaScript you would almost certainly be better off using a different server to run the PHP (e.g. Nginx).

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful insight. I'm still relatively new to fullstack so this is too much information to process :(

Comment: I have set up the server to grant permission to CORS.

Comment: Deployed and made sure they're hosted on the same server but still facing the same issue

Comment: You have to remove the server-side code from the React app entirely.

Comment: actually, I deployed them separately. :(

Comment: on the same server

Comment: as you adviced to do